# Módulo node reiniciando em múltiplas requisições

Tags: node.js

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto pessoal para fazer testes de performance em uma lista de sites e para isso eu estou usando os módulos do lighthouse e o chrome-launcher. Na minha aplicação está sendo lido uma lista de sites (url) e é feito as requisições para o lighthouse onde é retornado os devidos dados. O problema em questão é que esse módulo após ser chamado ele é reiniciado do nada e ele fica rodando 2x ou mais ao mesmo tempo. Eu estou usando promises para fazer essas interações. Usei métodos diferentes para fazer a requisição. Primeiro eu tentei usar o Q dando um resolve quando o response do lighthouse retornava. Tentei também usar o promise e dentro dele um for e atualmente estou usando o promise com uma função recursiva e nos 3 casos aconteceu o mesmo problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o fonte em questão:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const Q = require('q');
require('q-foreach')(Q);

module.exports.refreshData = function(application, req, res){
    console.log('\n\n\n caiu no modulo\n\n\n');

    //Lista de sites    
    fs.readFile('./clientes.json', function (err, data) {

        if (err) throw err;
        if(typeof data == 'object' && data.length > 0){
            json = JSON.parse(data);                            
        } else {
            json = [];
        }

        apiCall(json); 
    });

    function apiCall(response){
        var json = [];
        var i = 0;      

        const opts = {
            chromeFlags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']
        };

        fs.writeFile("./result.json", '', function(err){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        });        

        console.log(`\n\nN° de clientes do Magazord: ${response.length}\n\n`);

        auditClient = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            auditClient = audit(0);

            function audit(indexOfExec){
                let element = response[indexOfExec];
                let cliente = element['Cliente'];
                let url = element['Site URL'];
                let resultClients = [];

                chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
                    opts.port = chrome.port;
                    console.log(`${indexOfExec + 1} - Verificando o cliente ${cliente}`);

                    lighthouse(url, opts, null).then(results => {
                        chrome.kill().then(function(){
                            resultClients.push({
                                clienteNome: cliente,
                                clienteUrl: url,
                                favicon: url + 'image/favicon.png',
                                logo: url + 'image/logo.png',
                                performance: ((results.lhr.categories.performance.score) * 100).toFixed(0),
                                pwa: ((results.lhr.categories.pwa.score) * 100).toFixed(0),
                                accessibility: ((results.lhr.categories.accessibility.score) * 100).toFixed(0),
                                bestPractices: ((results.lhr.categories['best-practices'].score) * 100).toFixed(0),
                                seo: ((results.lhr.categories.seo.score) * 100).toFixed(0),
                                errosConsole: {
                                    'quantidade': results.lhr.audits['errors-in-console'].rawValue,
                                    'detalhes':  results.lhr.audits['errors-in-console'].details
                                },
                                requisicoes: results.lhr.audits['network-requests'].rawValue,
                                otimizacaoImagens: ((results.lhr.audits['uses-optimized-images'].score) * 100).toFixed(0),
                                tempoCarregamento: (results.lhr.audits.metrics.details.items[0].firstContentfulPaint).toFixed(2).slice(0, 3),
                                speedIndex: (results.lhr.audits['speed-index'].rawValue).toFixed(2).slice(0, 3),
                                dataAtualizacao: getDateTime()
                            });

                            fs.writeFile(`./audit-clients/${slug(cliente)}.json`, JSON.stringify(results.lhr), {flag: 'w+'}, function(err){
                                if(err){
                                    return console.log(`Erro ao tentar gravar os dados do audit do cliente ${cliente} ` + err);
                                }
                            })

                            fs.readFile('./result.json', {flag: 'rs+'}, function (err, data) {
                                if(err) {
                                    return console.log('Erro ao tentar recuperar os resultados do result.json ' + err);
                                }

                                if(typeof data == 'object' && data.length > 0){
                                    json = JSON.parse(data);
                                } else {
                                    json = [];
                                }

                                json.push(resultClients)

                                fs.writeFile("./result.json", JSON.stringify(json), {flag: 'w+'}, function(err){
                                    if(err){
                                        return console.log('Erro ao tentar salvar os resultados no result.json ' + err);
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                            console.log(`Finished - ${cliente}\n`);

                            if(indexOfExec < response.length -1){
                                audit(indexOfExec + 1)
                            }else{
                                console.log('Informações atualizadas com sucesso!');
                                resolve(resultClients);
                            }
                        })
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    }


    function renderView(data){
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

O projeto eu coloquei no [github](https://github.com/gabrielscordeiro/magazord-web-performance-seo-v2) para facilitar a visualização

Comment: Se eu clonar seu repositório e executar vai funcionar?

Comment: @Sorack vai funcionar sim